# What is the best way to make a QTableView's cells have up and down button pushed states in Qt?

Tags: user-interface, qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I'm trying to make the cells of a `QTableView` look like 3D clickable buttons. So that when you click on a cell, the button looks pushed. **Everyone seems to think I merely want to change the colour, I need to show images of a normal button, and a pushed button, that look 3-dimensional.**

I have done this already with calling `QTableView::setItemDelegate()`, with an appropriate `ItemDelegate` that will change the background of the cell when it's clicked. However I'm stuck at this point because I want some cells to be different coloured buttons based on the data they contain. So a cell with a low number would be a red button, that's also red when it's clicked, and the other cells would be different colours.

I can set the colour of the button with the `TableModel`, but once the button is clicked, there is no way for the `ItemDelegate` to know that it's supposed to be a different colour than the rest. How can you link the two so the `ItemDelegate` knows what colour it's supposed to be?

Also, is there simply a better way to make cells look like buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `QModelIndex::model()` from within the `ItemDelegate`'s `paint()` method, since it has a `QModelIndex` parameter. This gives you the `TableModel` for the data, which you can programatically decide what colour the cell's button will be.

However, this is still not as elegant as I'd hope. Does anyone know a better way to change the appearance of table cells when in both the up and down button push states?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you asked the index for the background color.

Something like this ...

```
QStyleOptionToolButton buttonOption;
const QStyleOptionViewItemV4& optionV4 = dynamic_cast<QStyleOptionViewItemV4&>(option);
//...
buttonOption.palette.setBrush( QPalette::Button, index.data( Qt::BackgroundColorRole ) ); 
//...
```

**I have feeling that its a bug in Qt and its must have been ...**

```
// model code  
if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole )
    return qvariant_cast<QBrush>( QBrush(Qt::red) );

// delegate code 
buttonOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Button, optionV4.backgroundBrush );
```

Because the `optionV4.backgroundBrus`h is correct in the `sizeHint` method  but is invalid in the `paint` method .  I see now reason why the `sizeHint` should have the background brush and the `paint` method not.  I'll report it to Nokia.

EDIT:
Looks like I was right and its a bug in < Qt4.5. 
[QStyleOptionViewItemV4 doesn't copy the icon and backgroundBrush](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?method=entry&id=222697)

Comment: I need to do this with up and down state images, not just background colours.

Comment: maybe you can use the Qt::CheckStateRole role for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not get the ID/row count of the table cell's row and then check it against the colour table that you may be having, and set the colour accordingly? I am not sure if I understood your question well or not.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but you'd have to have a separate colour table which isn't so elegant. I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Also I need button images, not colours. There is no way to set the button image and have it all work like it does with colours.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a data role for the background color, and in your item delegate, ask the model index what it's background color is (using `data( bg_color_role )` or something similar).   Then, in your model, you need to make sure the data function returns a color for the `bg_color_role` that is appropriate for the data being modeled.

Comment: Can you do this with images? I need to set a 3D button image for both down and up states for the cell.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to use the data method of the QModelIndex object you get on the paint method, and ask for a specific role (if you define a custom model, you can add your own roles, and give the information you need to the delegate in those roles.)

TimW, I think you have to fill the QStyleOptionViewItemV4 info by calling initStyleOption before.

Comment: Is there a background image role for mouse down and mouse up events? I need to make the table cells behave like a 3D button.

Comment: I think that you can use the state flag of the QStyleOptionViewItem to check if the item was pressed (there is QStyle::State_Sunken value). And together with that you can use the QStyleOptionButton to do the drawing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the requirement for a background image comes from. If you want the cells to look like `QPushButton`s, you should probably inherit from `QItemDelegate` and implement `paint()` to use `QStyle` to draw you a `QPushButton`, something like this:

```
QStyleOptionButton opt;
// fill 'opt' from the information from the model, and the style option that's passed in
style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &opt, painter );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using custom style sheets?

You could just apply the same stylesheet to every cell, and then change the background image / style to draw the 3D button images depending on whether or not it's selected.